# "New transaction cannot enlist in the specified transaction coordinator" at Linked Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle11g

When I try to call storedprocedure from linked server with "BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION" command , I get the following error.

```
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "LINKSERVER2" returned message "New transaction cannot enlist in the specified transaction coordinator. ".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "LINKSERVER2" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

When I run like this , procedure pass.

```
set @sql=  'begin INSERT INTO FEED.K_PACKING_CHARGE(org_code , sale_packing_size , amount)
VALUES (''2'' , ''100'' ,  ''3''); end;'

exec (@sql)  AT LINKSERVER_1 ;
```

but when I try to add "begin distributed transaction" command , I get error

```
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRAN
set @sql=  'begin INSERT INTO FEED.K_PACKING_CHARGE(org_code , sale_packing_size , amount)
VALUES (''2'' , ''100'' ,  ''3''); end;'

exec (@sql)  AT LINKSERVER_1 ;
 COMMIT
```

If I run create linked server at some computer , there is no problem. However I use two computer (one is MSSQL server and another is Oracle database)  , I get error.